# Off flavor of kegged Wheat beer

Tags: yeast, wheat

I brewed an AG wheat beer and used WLP351 as the yeast for this. Let it sit in the primary for near two weeks (66°F/19°C) and I did do a secondary on it for about another weak to try and decrease the sulfur smell. The sulfur seemed to have been gone so I kegged and force carbed/cold crashed for a week. Pour a glass and it now has a very overpowering yeasty/sulfur smell at the nose of the beer but finishes great. Any ideas on how to get rid of this? I have been venting off the keg that has not seemed to help at all. Thinking about removing it and let it come up to 70F and letting it sit for a week then try again? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 351. I stick with 380 now, the sulfur clears much quicker. For my hefe with 351, the flavor eventually went away, but it was in a secondary, not a keg. I think you should do what you're thinking: bring it to room temp and vent it regularly. Maybe give it a good swirl to get any yeast back into suspension.